# Focus Newly Opened Tabs

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, firefox, w3c, ecmascript-next

When opening a new window/tab, what is the earliest event I can listen for, that would tell me when that window is capable of receiving focus?

I have a web application that opens some clicked-things into new tabs via [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open), like this:

```
let url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61354349/";
window.open(url,'61354349').focus();
```

In Chromium, the new tab immediately gains focus as desired, but in Firefox it is treating `window.focus` like an async operation, in that, `WindowProxy.focus()` is being dispatched to the new window/tab before that window/tab has the ability to receive focus.

In this test example, you won't likely be able to reproduce the issue; I'm only able to experience this "focus gap" in my (more intensive) production environment.

In my production environment, if I call focus after a 100 millisecond delay (instead of immediately after `window.open`, it works; the tab gets focus in Firefox 75:

```
let url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61354349/";
let win = window.open(url,'61354349');
setTimeout(()=>{win.focus();},100);
```

I do not like solutions that wait a certain amount of milliseconds (on a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1632107)), because the number of milliseconds needed could vary per computer's performance.

If Firefox is going to treat `window.open` like an async operation, then ideally, it would return a promise that ultimately resolves a `WindowProxy` (once the window/tab is ready), instead of returning a `WindowProxy` immediately (that's incapable of dispatching focus to a window/tab that's not ready for it). However, returning a promise would obviously break existing code that's on the internet (maybe a promise based function should be proposed to the API spec writers). Firefox shouldn't return the `WindowProxy` until the window/tab is ready to receive focus. So, I've submitted [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1632107) about this.

This doesn't happen in Chromium (probably because Chromium doesn't return the `WindowProxy` until the new tab is actually ready to receive focus).

I'm looking for a workaround that's event-driven instead of timeout-based; I'm looking for an event that fires the same millisecond that the new tab is ready to receive focus.

I tried this:

```
let url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61354349/";
let win = window.open(url,'61354349');
win.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()
{
    win.focus();
});
```

This works. However, the `DOMContentLoaded` event happens a bit later than I'm wanting to focus the new tab. Is there an earlier event I can listen for?

Comment: When I just try the two lines from your first code block in Chrome or Firefox, I get a new tab that automatically gets focussed. (Assuming I allow automatic popups.) So not sure what actual problem needs solving here? In which situation excatly do you need to put the focus on this manually/explicitly via coding?

Comment: @CBroe : That's because in your environment, the window/tab is being created fast enough to be ready for focus. In my production environment, focus() is being called before the window/tab is ready to receive focus. I'm not sure why. The actual page I'm opening is a page located on the LAN. It returns in 4ms, but the content of that page has a bunch of async fetch operations that consolidate content from multiple sources. You wouldn't think that would matter, but I'm definitely expirencing a focus gap that goes away in 100ms.

Comment: [Mozilla Bug 1632107](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1632107)